# How do I speed up Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop?

Tags: 16.04, cpu-load

My laptop is 2GB, 1.2GHz dual core, LUKS. I installed Ubuntu in place of Windows XP and I thought it would go faster, but it's dog slow. This is what I have to live with:

[image: xload]

Comment: Xubuntu is a better choice for low end hardware. Generally, keep in mind that Windows XP is an OS from 2001.

Comment: Really? What does Ubuntu have that Xubuntu doesn't? I'd like to print and connect my iPhone and use Bluetooth (but Ubuntu bluetooth is broken anyways).

Comment: It could be media scanner 2.0

Comment: Well, it's actually easy to look up, read a review of something. The two have the same underlying system, but different DEs - Desktop Environments.

Comment: @Chloe there is Lubuntu. I  have it on a machine with half of yours parameters and it works good. It gives me much better performance than WinXP.

Comment: Using encryption will undoubtedly require more processing power than not. This is likely the root cause of perceived slowness.

Comment: @elder geek - That was on the back of my mind but I thought encryption was fast now and processors have special instructions for it? Mine is Intel Centrino. How do I tell how much time is spent on encryption? `top` doesn't show it - only apps like Firefox are on top. How do I turn encryption off to see if there is any difference?

Comment: @Chloe "Centrino" is a marketing term and honestly tells me very little. All processes use CPU cycles. As nothing is infinite everything you use for one purpose is unavailable for another purpose. This bit of logic is the source of my comment above.  [Encryption performance varies by Algorithm](http://www.cse.wustl.edu/~jain/cse567-06/ftp/encryption_perf/) <-This link will provide a comparison. Be that as it may,  turning off encryption is actually covered in several Q&A's here already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**First step:** Decrease swap use. This is specially useful fow low RAM (2GB or less) systems. 
You can check swap use by this command:

```
cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
```

This is generally set to 60.
To change the swappiness into a more sensible setting, type in the terminal

```
sudo nano /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf
```

At the end of this file, append the following line.

```
vm.swappiness=10
```

**Disable Unneeded Startup Applications.**

[image]

launch startup application by typing `startup` in dash and to disable a startup application, simply uncheck it.

**Disable Fancy Effects** 
 Use `compizconfig-settings-manager` to disable them

[image]

Install using

```
 sudo apt install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

and disable unwanted effects

**Install `preload`**

```
sudo apt install preload
```

This software memorize what applications you use most often and preload related libraries and binaries into memory so these applications can be launched faster.

Comment: Do I have to restart for `vm.swappiness` to take effect, or restart a service? I only had 3 startup items, Gnome, Indicator Application, and SSH cache. I also disabled `Alt-Tab` for Unity and enabled Static Application Switcher - much faster! I currently have Unity plugin disabled and it seems quite fast, but no task bar, window borders, or even menu bars so I guess I have to re-enable that. Neat!

Comment: @Chloe Yes you have to restart for `vm.swappiness` and also you can uncheck Gnome and SSH cache.  If disabling unity plugin causing some problem then re-enable it.